# Check if the row is the last one when looping through result set in PL/pgSQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Is something like this possible?

```
FOR row_var IN SELECT * FROM my_table LOOP
    -- ...
    IF is_last_row THEN
        -- do something...
    END IF;
END LOOP
```

The only thing that goes into my mind now is to select a count of the rows and compare it with `row_number()` in the loop.

Comment: How about simply running the code outside of the loop? That omits a lot of executions of the if statement too

Comment: @Wolph: I ended up doing just that but I leave the question as is just because it intrigues me :)

Comment: The only other reasonable option I can think of is the usage of `row_number()`... just using the same variable from outside the loop is the best solution anyhow. If you terminate the loop through `EXIT` the original variables are actually still available.

Comment: There is no well defined "last" row in a `SELECT` query without `ORDER BY`. The result is arbitrary.

Comment: There is not any flag like "row is last". You can use window function, but if you use it only for this purpose, then it is pretty significant overhead. Usually this is solved via row or record variable and work outside cycle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a very cheap and simple way. Your row variable `row_var` still holds the last row after the loop ends. Just use it then:

```
FOR row_var IN
   SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY ???
LOOP
    -- do something for every row here
END LOOP;

-- do something with row_var for the last row here
```

Aside from that, there is often a more efficient solution with plain SQL, depending on the undisclosed details of your use case ...

Comment: This only works if you want to do something extra for the last row, but doens't if you want to leave something out (such as UNION ALL).

Answer (score 3):

You don't need new variable nor addition query for `count()`.
If we assume you have primary key in table `my_table` in column `id` you can add one column with `WINDOW FUNCTION`:

```
FOR row_var IN SELECT lead(id) OVER() IS NULL AS is_last_row, * FROM my_table LOOP
-- ...
    IF row_var.is_last_row THEN
        -- do something...
    END IF;
END LOOP
```

If you have composite `PK` or have not `PK` at all on that table you may use:

```
SELECT lead(r) OVER()  IS NULL AS is_last_row, *
FROM (
    SELECT 1 as r, * FROM ruch.s_icd10
) sub
```

as `LOOP` query. That's only idea I have.

Answer (score 3):

If you selects rows ordered by a unique key, querying `last_id` should be cheaper than `count()` with `row_number()`, e.g.:

```
last_id := (select id from test order by id desc);
for rec in 
    select * from test order by id
loop
    if rec.id = last_id then
    ...
```